# tableview doesn't work properly in iPhone 6 simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

i have a tableview which gets data and shows them as a list. when i run the code on iPhone 5 simulator, it works fine. but when i test it on iPhone 6 simulator, two first cells have no functionality. but form the third cell, it works fine too. i'm new on swift programming and i have no idea why this happens.
here is a screenshot of my app:

[image]

when plus or minus sign or Add to order, they're not working. but after this two, from the third item, it works correctly.

here's code:

```
class DrinkDetailCell : UITableViewCell
{

@IBOutlet var title: UILabel!


@IBOutlet var price: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var image2: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var addBasket: UIButton!

var order = OrderDrink()

@IBAction func addToBasket(sender: AnyObject) {

    order.count = String( amounth )
    OrderDrinkTable().add(order)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName( "reloadPrice", object: nil)

    HUD.flash(.Success, delay: 1.0)
}

var amounth = 1

@IBAction func mines(sender: AnyObject) {

    if( amounth > 1 )
    {
        amounth -= 1
        quantity.text = String( amounth )
    }
}

@IBAction func plus(sender: AnyObject) {

    amounth += 1
    quantity.text = String( amounth )
}

@IBOutlet var quantity: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var quantity1: UILabel!


override init(style:  UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String? ) {
    super.init(style: style , reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}

}
```

Comment: Strange! Share that part of the code if you can.

Comment: I think some view overlay on tableview  so you cant tap on cell.

Comment: @Fennec i've added code

Comment: @mitulmarsonia i don't get it, so why works fine in iPhone 5?

Comment: Pause the app and print the view hierarchy

Comment: @mitulmarsonia thanks. that was a view overlay happens in iPhone 6 simulator

Comment: Great , When we use auto layout that time some constraint wrong then its happen.